# General Properties of Limits, Problems in understanding

Tags: calculus

So i have already understood that if the limit of two functions exist the limit of the sum, product and quocient, if the one in the denominator is different from zero, of them also exist. The problem is that i see in a  lot of places that this is true :

$$\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} &= \frac{\lim\limits_{x \to a} F(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to a} G(x)}\\
\lim\limits_{x \to a} (F(x)+G(x))&=\lim\limits_{x \to a} F(x) +\lim\limits_{x \to a} G(x)
\end{align*}$$

but i guess this is only true when they separately exist isn't it?

Comment: Yes; the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits *if they both exist*; the limit of the quotient is the quotient of the limits *if they both exist* **and** *the limit of the denominator is not $0$*.

Comment: Yes. For example if $F$ is $any$ real  function and $G(x)=-F(x)$ for every $x$ then $ \lim_{x\to a} F(x)+G(x) =0$  regardless of whether or not $\lim_{x\to a}F(x)$ exists.... Another property of limits is that if $0<A=\lim_{x\to a}F(x)\in \Bbb R$ and $0\ne B= \lim_{x\to a}G(x)\in \Bbb R $ then $\lim_{x\to a}F(x)^{G(x)}=A^B.$

Comment: Thank you guys,  these properties are spread such that its always true. What a problem

Comment: @Jordan: most books I know specifically begin with the premise that both $\lim F(x)$ and $\lim G(x)$ exist. Same with derivatives: you see $(f+g)' = f'+g'$ all the time, but this is premised on both $f'$ and $g'$ being defined.